# Remove zipped pairs with same entries in Python list

Tags: python, list, zip

I have a list of zipped pairs (for example A)

```
A = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 6), (0, 7), (1, 3), (1, 1), (2, 2)]
```

What's the best way in which I can remove all pairs where the first and the second entries equal each other (and create a new list)?

In the above example (**A**), the pairs that I wish to remove are **(0, 0)**, **(1, 1)** and **(2, 2)**. In this example, I wish the new list to look like this.

```
A_new = [(0, 1), (0, 6), (0, 7), (1, 3)]
```

Comment: **(2,1)** should be a typo ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use simple list comprehension with if clause that returns `True` for all unequal pairs that you want to keep:

```
>>> A = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 6), (0, 7), (1, 3), (1, 1), (2, 2)]
>>> [(x, y) for x, y in A if x != y]
[(0, 1), (0, 6), (0, 7), (1, 3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

using `filter`, it takes a judge function as first parameter to tell what element to keep and the iterable list as second parameter, `lambda` defines an anonymous function.

```
A_new = filter(lambda x: x[0] != x[1], A)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with `list comprehension`:

```
a = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 6), (0, 7), (1, 3), (1, 1), (2, 2)]
final = [k for k in a if k[0] != k[1]]
```

Output:

```
print(final)
>>> [(0, 1), (0, 6), (0, 7), (1, 3)]
```